# How to display the selected date value in datepicker on jquery querybuilder

Tags: jquery, datepicker, query-builder

How to set the textbox value into the datepicker in querybuilder. In this page http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html#widgets
When i click the textbox the datepicker displaying and marked today date. But i want to display the textbox date value "1991/11/17".

Now the default is look like

[image]

I want to display the datepicker like below when its displaying first,

[image]

How to do that. Please give any idea/suggestion that would be more helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: Just edit the date

Comment: Yes we may edit the date. But in my scenario, user shouldn't edit the date. It will populate automatically. And onemore thing, if the user doesn't select anything on the datepicker means the textbox value is going to empty. So, Please give any suggestion that would much helpful to me.

Comment: It seems a bug of the BootstrapJS Datepicker. They're using an obsolete version of bootstrap.js. You should try in your own environment with and up-to-date version of bootstrap.js

Comment: Yes, I tried with latest up-to-date bootstrap files. But no luck. Still i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an awful thing. You need to force Bootstrap to update the datepicker. To do that:

```
$("input.form-control").trigger("keyup");
```

I suggest you to filter inputs as much as possible to select only that one

**EDIT**

I found out the datepicker is not in BootstrapJS. 
It's from here ==> https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Try to update that to the latest version!

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!